# Do page arguments in hook_menu get sanitized?

Tags: routes, hooks

The title pretty much says it all.

If a callback is defined in a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6), such as

```
function mymodule_menu ()
{
    $items = array();

    $items["mymodule/foo/%"] = array(
        "page callback" => "mymodule_foo",
        "page arguments" => array(2),
        "access arguments" => array("mymodule permission"),
        "type" => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_foo ($parameter)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

When the callback gets called, has `$parameter` been sanitized, or is this the responsibility of the module?

I always sanitize in the module, but have never seen this stated either way and haven't found where callbacks get called from core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In D6**

[menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/6) calls the callback. However it gets it's arguments from [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/6), which uses arg.

I can't see any sanitizing in any of that. So it looks like the answer is no.

In any case extra sanitizing can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks.  This confirmed my suspicions, and also reminded me to try replacing space with underscores when searching core files for how something is implemented.

Comment: Extra sanitizing *can* hurt because double-escaped special characters can become hard to read.